# Hidden objects in list

Tags: r, package

I am creating a custom object for a package and I want to have a list of two objects, but for one of those elements to be 'hidden'

For example:

```
l = list(data = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6), hidden = list(obj1 = 1, obj2 = 2))
```

When I interact with the list I want to only interact with the `data` element and the other be only accessed specifically.

So, if i typed `l`

```
> l
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Which I can manage with a custom print method. But I also want to be able to do

```
> l[,1]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Which I don't think is possible with a custom print method.

I don't have any specific requirements for how the other element should be accessed, but something 'R friendly' I guess.

Is there a different class I should be using or creating a new class? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is a little broad/unclear. The `l[, 1]` could be solved with a custom class and a class-specific method. Does that answer your question? If not, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure - how would I implement that to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be cleaner for you to use attributes :

```
l <- list(data = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6),
          hidden = list(obj1 = 1, obj2 = 2))

foo <- function(x){
  attr(x$data,"hidden") <- x$hidden
  x$data
}

l <- foo(l) 
l
#   a b
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6

l[,1]
# [1] 1 2 3

attr(l,"hidden")
# 
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# [1] 2
#
```

Answer (score 4):

You could indeed define a custom class for your object. Let

```
class(l) <- "myclass"
```

Then you may define custom-specific methods for your functions of interest. For instance, in the case of `l[, 1]` we have

```
`[.myclass` <- function(x, ...) `[`(x[[1]], ...)
```

which takes this double list and then calls the usual `[` function on the first list element:

```
l[, 1]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

The same can be done with other functions, such as `print`:

```
fun.myclass <- function(x, ...) fun(x[[1]], ...)
```

And you still can always access the second object in the usual way,

```
l$hidden
# $obj1
# [1] 1
#
# $obj2
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow follow up question - but do you know a link that speaks more about S3 classes (this is S3 right?) and how to incorporate them into a package? Currently it works for me when I run this locally - but not when I install the package in a fresh session.

Comment: @SamPassmore, I also would expect it to work, but then I'm no expert in this area, so I suggest to go ahead and post a new question.